# T is a constant, may not be used as a variable

Tags: debugging, common-lisp

I'm writing common lisp code for a coding challenge, it's an rpg-esque puzzle where you need to calculate the total overkill damage dealt by the warrior. as I'm very new to common lisp, my code is likely pretty bad. Please refrain from posting general common lisp coding tips, unless they are relevant to the error. I plan on posting this code, after the error gets fixed, to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/**)

The code runs fine until inside `tick` (at the bottom) the condition `when (> overkill-damage 0)` is true. I'm using GNU Clisp 2.49 to run this code.

```
(defun timer (initialization-time interval)
    (list :init initialization-time :interval interval :ready nil :time-passed 0))

(defun tick-timer (timer)
    (let ((newtime (1+ (getf timer :time-passed))))
        (when (and (not (getf timer :ready)) (>= newtime (getf timer :init)))
            (setf (getf timer :ready) t))
        (setf (getf timer :time-passed) newtime)))

(defun timer-ready? (timer)
    (and
      (getf timer :ready)
      (= 0 (mod (getf timer :time-passed) (getf timer :interval)))))

(defun weapon (damage timer)
    (list :damage damage :timer timer))

(defun weapon-attack (weapon)
    (tick-timer (getf weapon :timer))
    (if (timer-ready? (getf weapon :timer))
        (getf weapon :damage)
        0))

(defun attack (character)
    (reduce #'(lambda (total weapon) (+ (weapon-attack weapon) total)) (getf character :weapons) :initial-value 0))

(defun attack-monster (monster damage)
    (- monster damage))

(defun calculate-overkill-damage (health)
    (if (> health 0)
        0
        (abs health)))

(defparameter *warrior* `(:weapons ,(list (weapon 35 (timer 0 4)))))
(defparameter *mage*    `(:weapons ,(list (weapon 80 (timer 2 8)))))
(defparameter *rogue*   `(:weapons ,(list (weapon 20 (timer 0 3))
                                  (weapon 30 (timer 0 4)))))

(defparameter *monsters* '(300 600 850 900 1100 3500))
(defparameter *current-monster* 0)
(defparameter *overkill* 0)
(defparameter *game-over* nil)

; I assume, for now, that when a monster dies, they will miss the rest of their attacks
(defun tick ()
  (sleep .1)
  (let* ((monster (nth *current-monster* *monsters*))
         (new-health (attack-monster monster (attack *warrior*)))
         (overkill-damage (calculate-overkill-damage new-health)))
    (format t "Attacking~%-------~%Attacking monster ~a, which has ~a health." *current-monster* monster)
    (format t "~%Dealt ~a overkill damage!" overkill-damage)
    (when (> overkill-damage 0)
        (do (format t "Dealt ~a overkill damage!" overkill-damage)
            (setf *overkill* (+ *overkill* overkill-damage))
            (format t "Total overkill damage is now ~a" *overkill*)
            (setf *current-monster* (1+ *current-monster*))
            (format t "Moving to next monster, ~a" *current-monster*)
            (when (= *current-monster* (1- (length *monsters*)))
                (setf *game-over* t))))
    (let* ((new-health (attack-monster monster (attack *mage*)))
           (new-health (attack-monster monster (attack *rogue*))))
      (setf (nth *current-monster* *monsters*) new-health)
      (format t "~%Monster is now at ~a health~%" (nth *current-monster* *monsters*)))))

(loop for x from 1 until (equal *game-over* t)
    do (tick))
```

The most important part is at the bottom of the code, the `tick` function. When this code gets run, I get the error `*** - LET: T is a constant, may not be used as a variable`.

This is what gets printed at execution:

```
TRUNCATED LOTS OF POINTLESS MESSAGES...
-------
Attacking monster 0, which has 10 health.
Dealt 0 overkill damage!
Monster is now at 10 health
Attacking
-------
Attacking monster 0, which has 10 health.
Dealt 25 overkill damage!
*** - LET: T is a constant, may not be used as a variable
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead.
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop
Break 1 [18]> :w

<1/172> #<SPECIAL-OPERATOR LET>
[170] EVAL frame for form 
(LET (FORMAT T "Dealt ~a overkill damage!" OVERKILL-DAMAGE)
 (TAGBODY #:LOOP-5923 (IF SETF (GO #:END-5924))
  (FORMAT T "Total overkill damage is now ~a" *OVERKILL*)
  (SETQ *CURRENT-MONSTER* (1+ *CURRENT-MONSTER*))
  (FORMAT T "Moving to next monster, ~a" *CURRENT-MONSTER*)
  (WHEN (= *CURRENT-MONSTER* (1- (LENGTH *MONSTERS*))) (SETQ *GAME-OVER* T))
  (PSETQ) (GO #:LOOP-5923) #:END-5924
  (RETURN-FROM NIL (PROGN *OVERKILL* (+ *OVERKILL* OVERKILL-DAMAGE)))))
Break 1 [18]>
```

That `:w` command shows code that isn't even there, I really don't understand what's going on there.
Even if I call macroexpand on `tick`, the code `(LET (FORMAT T "Dealt ~a overkill damage!" OVERKILL-DAMAGE)......` doesn't show up anywhere.

Does anyone know what's going on? Alternatively, if you have any CLISP debugging tips to help me pinpoint the error, please let me know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't understand what the code is supposed to do, but your error comes from `DO`: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm

As the documentation says, this is a loop whose first argument is a list of variables:

```
(do (format t "Dealt ~a overkill damage!" overkill-damage)
```

This tries to use `format`, `t`, `"Dealt ~a overkill damage!"`, and `overkill-damage` as variables.

If you just want to use multiple forms in the body of `when`, you don't have to do anything special. [`when`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_when_.htm#when) supports this out of the box:

```
(when (> overkill-damage 0)
    (format t "Dealt ~a overkill damage!" overkill-damage)
    (setf *overkill* (+ *overkill* overkill-damage))
    (format t "Total overkill damage is now ~a" *overkill*)
    ...)
```

Answer (score 6):

`DO` is a macro in Common Lisp. It is one of the older control structures in Lisp, like `DOLIST` and `DOTIMES`.

Since it is a macro, it might be difficult to debug. Especially when the `DO` macro does not do any syntax checking on its own.

For debugging in Lisp we can use the compiler and the interpreter. First let's use the compiler:

```
[1]> (defun test () (do (format t "hello world") (read)))
TEST
[2]> (compile 'test)

** - Continuable Error
in TEST : Illegal syntax in LET/LET*: "hello world"
```

The compiler gives an error message about *illegal syntax*. So there is a syntax error, but it does not make it clear where it is coming from. Since there is no `LET`or `LET*` in the code, it must come from some syntax transformation -> macro. `DEFUN` and `DO` are macros.

```
(macro-function 'do) -> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION DO>
```

The next step is to look at the macro expansion of the `DO` form:

```
[4]> (macroexpand-1 '(do (format t "hello world") (read)))
(BLOCK NIL
 (LET (FORMAT T "hello world")
  (TAGBODY #:LOOP-3239 (IF READ (GO #:END-3240)) (PSETQ) (GO #:LOOP-3239) #:END-3240
   (RETURN-FROM NIL (PROGN))))) ;
T
```

In above form we see the `LET` and we can see that the binding is wrong. So the `DO` form is probably wrong.

This is now a perfect time to check the syntax of `do`: see the HyperSpec entry for [DO](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm#do). Usually that should be clear enough to find the syntax error.

We can also use the CLISP interpreter and step through the example:

```
[5]> (step (test))
step 1 --> (TEST)
Step 1 [6]> step
step 2 --> (BLOCK NIL (LET (FORMAT T "hello world") (TAGBODY #:LOOP-3210 # # ...)))
Step 2 [7]> step
step 3 --> (LET (FORMAT T "hello world") (TAGBODY #:LOOP-3210 (IF READ #) (PSETQ) ...))
Step 3 [8]> step

*** - LET: T is a constant, may not be used as a variable
```

Basically we see the code transformation done in each step.

Since Common Lisp has many implementations, there are some with better error messages. For example SBCL:

```
* (defun test () (do (format t "hello world") (read)))
; in: DEFUN TEST
;     (DO (FORMAT
;          T
;          "hello world")
;         (READ))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of
;   (DO (FORMAT
;        T
;        "hello world")
;       (READ)).
;   Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept.
;
;    "hello world" is an illegal form for a DO varlist.
;
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
```

That's better.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `do` defines the local variables to the loop, as a `let` does; you are using it as the start of the body.

Comment: Oh ok, I seem to be mistaken. I thought `do` simply sequentially executed every statement in its body. What function *does* do that then?

Comment: @Azeirah [`progn`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm#progn), but you don't even need that in this case. See my answer.